# Comparision of string in android

Tags: java, android, string

Comparision not working in android using either '==' or .equals
This is a part of my code ....inside the set onclick listener in btn1 the if statement is not working ....i also tried by adding .toString but its not working

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView value;
    Button btn1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        value=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (value.equals("+") || value.equals("-")|| value.equals("*")||      value.toString().equals("/")){
                value.setText("");
            }
            value.append("1");
            result.append("1");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot, it would be helpful.

Comment: it is not possible equal has supported from API level 1

Comment: you can use `equalsIgnoreCase` also

Comment: #Saif Arsalan Did you solve yet ?

Comment: the api problem is solved ...but the code is not working ...actully i am comparing a variable which gets input from a textView and comparing it with a string using '=='. I also used .equals() but it didnt work....I am beginner in programming so am little bit confused

Comment: @SaifArsalan check my answer . use `matches`

Comment: ... The problem is he is comparing a String to a TextView object which fundamentally shouldn't work. Or am I missing something? Call value.getText().toString(). If the TextView equals method only checks the strings, then that equals method was implemented wrong, it has more fields than that to ensure proper equality.

Comment: @LucasCrawford You are right .  need to use `.getText().toString();`

Comment: @SaifArsalan Move ahead .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

You should use `.getText().toString();` method At first.

Finally

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       String Str_Compare = value.getText().toString();
        if (Str_Compare.equals("+") || Str_Compare.equals("-")|| Str_Compare.equals("*")||      Str_Compare.toString().equals("/")){
            value.setText("");
        }
        value.append("1");
        result.append("1");
    }
});
```

`equals()` method Added in **API level 1** .

> equals() method compares the characters inside a String object. The
>   == operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

**equals() Added in API level 1**

> Can I raise my API level?

You could set your minSdkVersion to 19.

check API [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Versions)

If you say that your minSdkVersion is 16, then devices running a version of Android older than that cannot run your app.